# Snackbar Overlapping Floating Action Button Through Fragment Navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, floating-action-button, android-snackbar

I've having an strange issue of `Snackbar` overlapping a `floating action button` that I have in the main view of the application. For context, I will provide a short clip of the issue I'm experiencing. I initiate the `snackbar` from a separate fragment after completing an action (update or add) then return to the main view (list fragment), in which the `snackbar` will be shown, but the `snackbar` overlaps the floating action button rather than moving it up slightly even when the list fragment layout contains a coordinator layout. Any ideas to work around this issue?

Current Behavior:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tVC4.gif

Desired Behavior:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W51A9.gif

Below is the code I call when navigating back to the main fragment (list fragment).

```
createSnackBar(requireView(),R.string.successfully_updated, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_updateFragment_to_listFragment)
```

Implementation of createSnackBar function.

```
fun createSnackBar(view: View, @StringRes message: Int, duration: Int) {
    val resources = view.resources
    val snackBar = Snackbar.make(view, resources.getString(message), duration)
    snackBar.show()
}
```

Comment: whenever you navigate  Instead of showing snackbar in update fragment (before navigation), show it in list fragment once you return

Comment: @ShobhithYadav How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the fab button to the anchor view of the `SnackBar` using [`setAnchorView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/snackbar/BaseTransientBottomBar#setAnchorView(int))

```
fun createSnackBar(view: View, @StringRes message: Int, duration: Int) {
    val resources = view.resources
    val snackBar = Snackbar.make(view, resources.getString(message), duration)
    snackBar.setAnchorView(R.id.myFab) // replace myFab with your fab button id
    snackBar.show()
}
```